# How to clear mat-datepicker in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I clear an Angular Material Datepicker with an button click?

I've tried 
.date
.value
.clear
.reset
.resetDate

None of them seem to clear the Datepicker.

HTML:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDatePicker" placeholder="From Date" disabled>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #fromDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="toDatePicker" placeholder="To Date" disabled>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #toDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
```

Typescript:

```
  @ViewChild('fromDatePicker') fromDate: any;
  @ViewChild('toDatePicker') toDate: any;

  resetForm() {
    this.searchString.nativeElement.value = "";
    this.fromDate.value = undefined;

    this.fromDate.date = null;
    this.toDate.date = undefined;

  };
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must query for the `matInput` element.

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('fromInput', {
  read: MatInput
}) fromInput: MatInput;

@ViewChild('toInput', {
  read: MatInput
}) toInput: MatInput;

resetForm() {
  this.fromInput.value = '';
  this.toInput.value = '';
}
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input #fromInput matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDatePicker" placeholder="From Date" disabled>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #fromDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input #toInput matInput [matDatepicker]="toDatePicker" placeholder="To Date" disabled>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #toDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nv5qts)

Answer (score 7):

**HTML**

```
  <mat-datepicker (opened)="resetPicker()" class="mat-datepicker" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

**TS**

```
  @ViewChild(MatDatepicker)
  picker: MatDatepicker<Moment>;
```

```
  resetPicker() {
    this.picker.select(undefined);
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for Angular 8 (none of the higher-voted answers worked for me).

Comment: Can you tell me what import you used for the `Moment` property? It does not seem to be within Angular

Comment: Nvm, looks like using `Moment` would be dependent on using `MatMomentDateModule` [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings).

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do it is setting the related variable *undefined*:

HTML:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input [(ngModel)]="fromDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDatePicker" placeholder="From Date" disabled>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #fromDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input [(ngModel)]="toDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="toDatePicker" placeholder="To Date" disabled>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #toDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button (click)="resetForm()">Reset</button>
```

Typescript:

```
  resetForm() {
    this.fromDate = undefined;
    this.toDate = undefined;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done in this way:

**component.ts**

```
resetForm(fromInput, toInput) {
  fromInput.value = '';
  toInput.value = '';
}
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input #fromInput matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDatePicker" placeholder="From Date" disabled>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #fromDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input #toInput matInput [matDatepicker]="toDatePicker" placeholder="To Date" disabled>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="toDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #toDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="resetForm(fromInput, toInput)">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

With a formControl you can also do it in a generic way

```
 genericDateChangedWithKeyboard(value, formControlName) {
if (value.target.value == "") {
  this.formGroup.controls[formControlName].setValue(null);
}
```

"value" is here the value you pass to the inpu-field

Answer (score 0):

```
Worked for me in this way:
```

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input #fromInput matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDatePicker" placeholder="From Date" disabled>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix (click)="clearDate(fromInput)">
     <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>clear</mat-icon>
  <mat-datepicker #fromDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
   clearDate(date: HTMLInputElement) {
      date.value = "";
    }
```