# Angular Material - How can I clear mat-datepicker calendar selection?

Tags: angular, angular-material

My HTML code is:

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
        <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
          <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" #startDateInput />
          <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" #endDateInput />
        </mat-date-range-input>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
     </mat-form-field>
     <button class="btn" (click)="resetInformation()">Clear</button>
```

And my TS code is:

```
  @ViewChild('startDateInput', { static: false }) startDateInput?: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @ViewChild('endDateInput', { static: false }) endDateInput?: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(null),
    end: new FormControl(null),
  });

  resetInformation() {
    this.startDateInput!.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.endDateInput!.nativeElement.value = '';

    this.range.reset();
  }
```

I am using an Angular Materials Component, `Datepicker` and when I try to clear the information (from the inputs), it doesn't clear the selection made in the calendar, as shown in the below picture:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can remove the selection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear mat-datepicker in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983740/how-to-clear-mat-datepicker-in-angular-5)

Comment: @RameshRajendran Nope, I've checked that question when doing mine. None of the answers helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `forms` integration with your `DatePicker` to be able to set or reset values.

Template :

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>

  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker" [formGroup]="range">
    <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" formControlName="start" />
    <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" formControlName="end" />
  </mat-date-range-input>

  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>

<button class="btn" (click)="resetInformation()">Clear</button>
```

Main additions (vs your code) :

- `[formGroup]="range"` on `mat-date-range-input` to be linked with `FormGroup` defined in `app.component.ts`
- `formControlName="start"` and `formControlName="end"` added on each `input` to be linked with each control of form group.

Component :

```js
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
    end: new FormControl<Date | null>(null),
  }); 

  resetInformation() {
    this.range.reset();
  }
}
```

More details on [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-range-input-forms-integration)

Comment: This was the answer! Thank you very much.